# After reading a file ruby leaves it open/locked on Windows XP

Tags: ruby

I read a text file to get some info from it and later on I need to rename the directory that the file sits in. I am not able do to that because the file is locked. If I comment out the function that reads from the file or if I manually unlock the file (unlocker utility) everything goes fine.

I am on ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]

This line leaves the file open `File.open(file).readlines.each{|line|`

These two lines leave the file open

```
    my_file=File.open(file,"r")
    my_file.collect {|line|
```

unless I close the file at the end using `my_file.close`

The [man for core 1.8.7 of IO.html#method-c-open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/IO.html#method-c-open) states

> If the optional code block is given, it will be passed io as an argument, and the IO object will automatically be closed when the block terminates.

So I don't understand why the file is still open.

What would be the one line code in 1.8.7 to read a text file and close it automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is clear. However, you're passing the block to `collect`. And since you're not passing it to `open`, you are responsible for closing the file.

To have file auto-closed, try this:

```
File.open(file,"r") do |f|
  f.collect # or whatever
end
```

Comment: So how would I read a text file into an array using open on one line?

Comment: @Radek: and when would "one line" ever be a valid requirement? (HINT: never)

Comment: @EdS.: in job interviews, probably? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: I said "valid" :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the block to close the file automagically without passing the file handle to a block, you can use the IO#readlines method of your File object.

```
array_of_lines = File.readlines('/tmp/foo')
```

This will read the entire contents of the file, then close the file handle. It's a good option whenever a file is small enough to fit easily into memory.

Comment: Conceptually, yes. A file slurp needs to allocate space for the entire file; #each_line and friends only needs to allocate space for a line at a time.

Comment: So if I read a big file into an array using File.readlines() how can I free the memory?

Comment: With `readlines` you have to read entire file into memory. When you're done with the lines, GC will take care of them.

Comment: If the file was read into an array it will stay available even after reading from the array, won't it.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the block directly to the "open" call:

```ruby
File.open(file, 'r') do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    # Process each line
  end
end
```

Or if you just want the file contents in a single shot then try this:

```ruby
lines = File.read(file).split(/\r?\n/)
```

Comment: Let's say I have a condition on the level of 'line'. If true I want to  quit processing the file. How can I do that?